# PHP Script called by fetch twice is blocking

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 fetch functions calling the same PHP Script. The whole content of the PHP-Script is the following:

```
<?php

session_write_close();
sleep(10);
```

`session_write_close();` is only there to make sure the Session is really closed. However the first Script finishes after ~10 Seconds and the second Script after ~20 Seconds:

[image: Network Tab]

Why is Script 1 blocking Script 2?

For the sake of completeness here is the JavaScript:

```
async function test() {
    fetch('api/v1/test')
    fetch('api/v1/test')
}
test();
```

Comment: unable to replicate this observed result in tests. There must be other factors involved.

Comment: _"The whole content of the PHP-Script is the following"_ - so you have your PHP explicitly configured to _auto-start_ the session across all scripts then? Because if not, then what session are you even trying to write and close here ...

Comment: Found something interesting in the comments of [php.net/session_write_close](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-write-close.php#120452) "if You have enabled output buffering (default in PHP 7+). You have to set output_buffering = Off in php.ini, otherwise session won't be closed immediately." this might solve your issue.

Comment: @CBroe It does not make a difference if I add session_write_close() or not. I added it just to make clear that a locked session file is not the root of my Problem.

Comment: @mhaendler Turning the output_buffer off does not make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone else who faces the same problem: If you develop locally on the Built-In web server you need the following setting: `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS`

Windows is currently not supported and PHP >=7.4 is needed.

Link to the documentation: [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: To have it actually work (with more than one worker), PHP 8.0+ recommended (not because 7.4 is EOL by the PHP project, but because it had bugs in this regard, fixed in 8). And the setting is not necessarily needed, having the server single threaded allows you to debug each request sequentially which is much easier than compared to congruently.

Comment: What server is it? The code should work as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "What server"?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment above, I am unable to replicate the `blocking` behaviour you mention.

Using essentially the same function and sending a minimal GET request to the PHP endpoint (in this case the same page ) that does essentially the same as the original the requests all return content almost together.

```
<?php
    $t=10;

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['task'], $_GET['seq'], $_GET['func'] ) && $_GET['task']=='test' ){
        session_write_close();
        sleep( $t );
        
        exit( 'ok: sequence: ' . $_GET['seq'] . ' func: ' . $_GET['func'] . ' date: ' . date( DATE_ATOM )  );
    }
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Blocking or not-blocking?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='results'><div>
        
        <script>
        
            const callback=(r)=>{
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += `${r}<br />`;
            }
            
            const test=()=>{
                fetch('?task=test&seq=1&func=1')
                    .then(r=>r.text())
                    .then(callback);
                    
                fetch('?task=test&seq=2&func=1')
                    .then(r=>r.text())
                    .then(callback);
                    
            };
            async function test2() {
                fetch('?task=test&seq=1&func=2')
                    .then(r=>r.text())
                    .then(callback);
                    
                fetch('?task=test&seq=2&func=2')
                    .then(r=>r.text())
                    .then(callback);    
            }
            
            callback(`Begin Tests: ${new Date()}`);
            test();
            test2();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This yields, for example:

```
Begin Tests: Thu Feb 09 2023 12:18:59 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
ok: sequence: 1 func: 1 date: 2023-02-09T12:19:09+00:00
ok: sequence: 2 func: 1 date: 2023-02-09T12:19:09+00:00
ok: sequence: 1 func: 2 date: 2023-02-09T12:19:09+00:00
ok: sequence: 2 func: 2 date: 2023-02-09T12:19:09+00:00
```

Comment: I just copied your script and in my case there is a 10 Second difference in the timestamps

Comment: There must be some other factor at play then

Comment: Any Idea where to look at? Even if I call 2 different Scripts, Script 2 will only start after Script 1 finishes.

Comment: is this on your local development server or live? Apache? Nginx? Is the session path directory correctly writable? Have you tweaked your server config? What is the maximum simultaneous connections allowed per client?

Comment: Thanks, that put me in the right direction. I just updated my Question.

Comment: :-) I'm glad that you were able to work your way through this issue to find a solution - If I helped it was only a little, you solved this! Good luck